# date_select not preserving date param from new to edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date, datetime

User starts on the new form page, after they submit, they're immediately redirected to an edit page where they see the info they just submitted and have an opportunity to make changes. Previously posted data should carry over, and right now they do except for the date (`:startdate` and `:enddate`)...

I.e., if you enter email: john@gmail.com on the new page and then POST, at the edit page, john@gmail.com is already visible, in case you need to make changes. However the date fields keep resetting to the current date.

Thanks for the help!

**CONTROLLER code**

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @requestrecord = Request.new
  end

  def create
    @requestrecord = Request.new(request_params)
    if @requestrecord.save
      redirect_to edit_request_path(@requestrecord.edit_id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit 
    @requestrecord = Request.find_by_edit_id(params[:edit_id])
  end

  def update
    @requestrecord = Request.find_by_edit_id(params[:edit_id])
    @requestrecord.attributes = request_params
  end

private
  def request_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:email, :startdate, :enddate, :edit_id) #edit_id is auto-gen by a method defined in the model
  end
```

**VIEW code**

```
<%= form_for @requestrecord, :html=> {:id => 'form'} do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :email, "Email we will use to contact you" %>
       <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "How do we get in touch with you?" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label "Item(s) needed from: " %>
       <%= date_select(:request, :startdate, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 1) %>
       <%= f.label " to: " %>
       <%= date_select(:request,   :enddate, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 1) %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Go!", class: "btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" %>

<% end %>
```

**MODEL code**

```
  private

    def Request.new_edit_id
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def create_edit_id
      self.edit_id = Request.new_edit_id
    end
```

**Things I have tried (that have not worked)**

- Change`:startdate` and `:enddate` column type from `:datetime` to `:date`
- Since both edit and new pages are drawing from the same partial with the form, I thought maybe the native default date was constantly over-riding the params, so I tried to include the option `include_blank: true`, this didn't work, now the date just resets to blanks on the edit page
- Despite the dates resetting, to be clear they were always being saved in the database, so the params were passed through. But just to be clear, I've tried a number of different param options, from `"startdate(1i)", "startdate(2i)", "startdate(3i)"` to `:startdate => []` to separating the startdate completely as a separate param request as per this [example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/331359-date-handling-in-controller-permit-function/)

Comment: you are talking about `:startdate` attribute?

Comment: both `:startdate` and `:enddate`

Comment: I tried to replicate what you doing (except I don't have edit_id) and is working fine. whatever date I put shows in edit page. try without `edit_id` just to see if that's the problem. do: `edit_request_path(@requestrecord)`. also, check `rails console` to see which date is saved to the db

Comment: Well first thanks for being so thorough! I just tried it without edit_id, and it still doesn't work. And I double checked the console, the date is definitely being saved. Would you mind sharing the code you wrote? A github perhaps?

Comment: here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/WallyAli/2ffd62eae18af5db59b6). all I did was scaffold the code and change only one line in the controller: `redirect_to edit_request_path(@request)`. in your form, try removing `start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 1` to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Ok that didn't work and I don't see any differences. Ugh... thank you for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAH! Apparently unlike for every other parameter in a simple form, `date_select` constantly defaults back to the default (i.e., today, or blank, whatever you tell it) EVEN IF you do NOT specify default!

I'm using a form as a partial for both new & edit pages. When the edit page is rendered, Rails is smart enough to replace the placeholder for `:email` with whatever the previously POSTED `:params` for `:email` was, BUT for the date, you have to specifically tell it that the default should be the already stored date for that instance variable.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :email, "Email we will use to contact you" %>
   <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "How do we get in touch with you?" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <%= date_select(:request, :startdate, default: @requestrecord.startdate, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 1) %>
</div>
```